# Finding the height of a binary tree recursively or iteratively?

Tags: java, recursion, binary, iteration, binary-tree

Could anyone check if the code below for height is correct? I am not sure if I can use recursion since `public int height()` has no arguments passed in.  I am assuming that the height of an empty tree is 0.

```
public class BinaryTree {
    private class Node {
        String value;
        Node left;
        Node right
    }

    Node root;

    // Assume there is a constructor and various methods here

    public int height() {
        if (Node == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return 1 + math.max(left.height(), right.height());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. Some code chunks moved to their proper places, the null check in the recursive step rewritten, a little sample added:

```
public class BinaryTree {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node sports = new Node();

    Node individual = new Node();
    Node team = new Node();
    sports.left = individual;
    sports.right = team;

    Node javelin = new Node();
    individual.left = javelin;

    System.out.println(sports.height()); // Return 3
}

private static class Node {

    Node left;
    Node right;

    public int height() {
        return 1 + Math.max(left == null ? 0 : left.height(), right == null ? 0 : right.height());
    }

}

}
```